# Is it possible to call on one function, or another function, based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out how to call either one function, or the other function based on user input after being asked a simple one or the other type question.

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible. Just use an `if`/`else`. Perhaps you've tried something and run into difficulty?

Comment: Yes. Programming is all about making decisions like that. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Here's a miniature example to get you started. This method, as opposed to an `if / else` construct, is known as function *dispatching*.

```
def func1():
    return 'Function1 result'

def func2():
    return 'Function2 result'

def func3():
    return 'Function3 result'

def func_default():
    return 'Function default result'

d = {1: func1, 2: func2, 3: func3}

try:
    x = int(input('What function do you wish to run?'))   
    result = d.get(x, func_default)()
    print(result)

except ValueError:
    print('Please rerun and enter an integer.')
```

Comment: @A.Wenn made a decent point (albeit that they posted an answer because they can't comment). This will always give `func_default()` in Python 3 because `input` returns a string.

Comment: @roganjosh, fair point. updated.